# REST API Guzzle POST gives timeout but the same call works if I run it on the server cli

Tags: 8

I have Drupal running in a docker container and nginx running in another container.

When I do the login call through postman or directly on the webserver cli it works perfectly.
But when I do call from within my application I get a timeout after 30 seconds.

From server:

> wodby@php.container:/var/www/html $ curl -X POST \
>     'http://api.swappr.localhost/user/login?_format=json' \
>     -H 'Postman-Token: a9c80844-ed69-4d24-b205-6475b7e469dc' \
>     -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
>     -d '{"name":"logintest2@gmail.com", "pass":"password"}'
>   {"current_user":{"uid":"21","name":"logintest2@gmail.com"},"csrf_token":"yf5YBYyY4YvXCcufLyTWeKnvbhq5sdcZHpgmsVDeSRY","logout_token":"PEarVS7vPi5idARarGQzrrXAYcJL9YkiXmoHw_a7yJE"}

In code:

```
$response = \Drupal::httpClient()->post(
            'http://api.swappr.localhost/user/login?_format=hal_json',
            ['name' => 'logintest2@gmail.com', 'pass' => 'password']
        );

cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Anyone knows what could cause this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a networking problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay turns out it was xdebug. I had to allow more simultaneous connections in the PHP Debug settings of PHP Storm.